# ASP MVC 5 jqGrid treegrid - отображение данных

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc, mvc, treeview, jqgrid

Всем привет, MVC начал изучать совсем недавно.
Мне нужно отображать категории и подкатегории в моей системе ввиде дерева.
С обычным JQGrid проблем нету, данные отдаю с сервера в формате Json. Что делать с деревом не знаю :\ Перечитал уже массу всего...

Существует модель:

```
public class CategoriesViewModel
{
    public int CategoryID { get; set; } //ID
    public string Title { get; set; } //Название
    public int? ParentCategoryID { get; set; } //ID Родителя, null -если топ
}
```

Я думаю, что проблема в формате данных, которые я отдаю. Это вариант для обычного грида. Но при таком формате неясно, где родительская-дочерняя часть.
Контроллер:

```
public static IEnumerable<CategoriesViewModel> GetCategories(String sidx, String sord)
{
    using (var db = new RecipeManagmentSystemEntities())
    {
        String orderBytext = String.Format("it.{0} {1}", sidx, sord);
        var result = (from p in db.Category.OrderBy(x => x.CategoryID)
                 select new CategoriesViewModel
                 {
                     CategoryID = p.CategoryID,
                     ParentCategoryID = p.ParentCategoryID,
                     Title = p.Title
                 }).ToList();
        return result;
    }
}

public JsonResult CategoriesData(string sidx, string sord, int page, int rows)
{
    var list = GetCategories(sidx, sord);
    var pageIndex = Convert.ToInt32(page) - 1;
    var pageSize = rows;
    var totalRecords = list.Count();
    var totalPages = (int)Math.Ceiling(totalRecords / (float)pageSize);
    list = (list.Skip(pageIndex * pageSize).Take(pageSize)).ToList();
    var jsonData = new
    {
        total = totalPages, page,
        records = totalRecords,
        rows = (from p in list
             select new
             {
                 i = p.CategoryID.ToString(),
                 cell = new[] 
                 {
                     p.CategoryID.ToString(),
                     p.ParentCategoryID.ToString(),
                     p.Title
                 }
             }).ToArray()
     };

     return Json(jsonData, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
}
```

Скрипт tree-grida:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
         $('#treeGrid').jqGrid({
             url: '@Url.Action("CategoriesData")',
             datatype: "json",
             height: "auto",
             mType: 'GET',
             treeGridModel: 'adjacency',
             colNames: ['CategoryID', 'Title', 'ParentCategoryID'],
             colModel: [
                 { name: 'CategoryID', index: 'CategoryID', width: 3,
stype: 'text', key: true },
                 { name: 'Title', index: 'Title' },
                 { name: 'ParentCategoryID', index:'ParentCategoryID' }
              ],
                treeGrid: true,
                loadonce: true,
                caption: "my tree",
                ExpandColumn: "Title",
                ExpandColClick: true,
                autowidth: true
        });
   });
</script>
```

Comment: случайно увидел этот старый вопрос. Как в коде клиента, так и в коде сервера много проблем, но самые важные проблемы, которые бы я выделил, три: 1) формат возвращаемых данных должен быть совершенно другой (содержать поля `level`, `parent`, `isLeaf`, `expanded`, `loaded`); 2) `CategoriesData` должна иметь другие параметры `nodeid`, `parentid`, `n_level`; 3) `CategoriesData` должна возвращать этемены либо верхнего уровня, либо дочернего уровня для `parentid`. Можно вообще говоря, возвращать элементы более чем одного уровня, но порядок возвращаемых элементов очень важен и должен быть как в дереве